# Maximum Size that a Boost Message Queue can Handle?

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue

What is the maximum size a Boost Message Queue can Handle?

When I am sending and receiving the below structure by using Boost binary serialization it is working fine.

```
typedef struct  {
int  msg_type;
char msg_name[100];

union {
    struct {
        int     ID;
        std::string    ReportedTime;
        char    ReceivedAt[200];
        int     Number;
        int     Priority;



    } mess1;

    struct  {
        char    host_ip[20];
        char    mac_addr[30];
        char    time_stamp[100];
    } mess2;
} struct_type;
}msg_struct;
```

`#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(msg_struct)`

But when I making the size of `ReceivedAt[2000]` to 2000 or adding a new char array variable.

It is throwing the following exception and the core is getting dumped.

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'
  what():  boost::interprocess_exception::library_error`

`Aborted (core dumped)`

**Edit**

Send

```
int  ControlQueue::pushMessage(msg_struct* msg)
{
int q_size = vamsgq->get_num_msg();
int retVal = 0;


    lockQueue();

//imp->ID=1;
//strcpy(imp->ReceivedAt,"10-07-14");


    std::stringstream oss;

    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);
    strncpy(msg->msg_name,"msg_name",sizeof(msg->msg_name));

   oa << boost::serialization::make_array(msg, 1);


    std::string serialized_string(oss.str());

    vamsgq->send(serialized_string.data(), serialized_string.size(), 0);

    std::cout <<"\n sendig type="<< msg->msg_name << std::endl;


    if((retVal = pthread_cond_signal(&m_qCondSignal)) != 0)
    {
       cout<<__FILE__<<__LINE__<<
        "{ControlQueue %x} Unable to send Cond Signal",this);
    }

    unlockQueue();


return 1;
}
```

Recieve:

```
msg_struct* ControlQueue::getMsg()
{
int retVal = 0;
message_queue::size_type recvd_size;
unsigned int priority;
lockQueue();

while(vamsgq->get_num_msg()==0)
{
    if((retVal = pthread_cond_wait(&m_qCondSignal, &m_qMutex)) != 0)
    {
        cout<<__FILE__<<__LINE__<<"getMsg {ControlQueue } Unable to Cond Signal";
        unlockQueue();
        return NULL;
    }
}
msg_struct *l_msg_struct = NULL;

if(vamsgq->get_num_msg())
{

l_msg_struct=new msg_struct();

std::stringstream iss;
std::string serialized_string;
serialized_string.resize(MAX_SIZE);

vamsgq->receive(&serialized_string[0], MAX_SIZE, recvd_size, priority);
iss << serialized_string;

boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(iss);
ia >> boost::serialization::make_array(l_msg_struct, 1);


 std::cout <<"Recieving="<< l_msg_struct->msg_name << std::endl;

}
else
{
    cout<<__FILE__<<__LINE__<<"getMsg {ControlQueue } m_MsgQ empty..";
}

unlockQueue();

return l_msg_struct;

}
```

The Send and Receive both are running in different threads the only problem what I am getting is after increasing the size of structure or adding an char array variable.

And the exception is getting thrown by the `vamsgq->send()` method, Creation method(message queue) is working fine. And I am also increasing the size of Message that message queue is going to store.

Is there any complete documentation online for the boost::message_queue.

Comment: can you post a minimal SSCCE? We cannot psychicly  get the exception information out. You're going to have to handle the exception or trace the program flow/breakpoint at the throw site to see where it fails.

Comment: @sehe Thanks. I am thinking that it is happening because I am using two threads working parallely one for sending and one for receiving and IPC is used for inter-process comm. But I am using proper listeners for activating thread 2 to read. And it is working fine for small data Structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You broke the requirement for

   ```
   BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(msg_struct)
   ```

   by no longer keeping the `msg_struct` a POD type:

   ```
   static_assert(boost::is_pod<msg_struct>::value, "msg_struct must be POD");
   ```

   will fail to compile. (In fact, with the `msg_struct` shown using `std::string`, I think default construction should fail to compile, so the `new msg_struct()` line in your example confuses me).
2. Also you don't show the construction of the message-queue, so I can't tell how you determine the maximum message size. This might be inadequately dimensioned. See below for two approaches that use/check the size limitations.

Here's what would work:

#### [Solution A] All POD data, no serialization

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

typedef struct {
    int  msg_type;
    char msg_name[100];

    union {
        struct {
            int  ID;
            char ReportedTime[100];
            char ReceivedAt[2000];
            int  Number;
            int  Priority;
        } mess1;

        struct  {
            char host_ip[20];
            char mac_addr[30];
            char time_stamp[100];
        } mess2;
    } struct_type;
} msg_struct;

static_assert(boost::is_pod<msg_struct>::value, "msg_struct must be POD");
#include <boost/serialization/is_bitwise_serializable.hpp>
BOOST_IS_BITWISE_SERIALIZABLE(msg_struct)

namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;

int main() {
    ipc::message_queue queue(ipc::open_or_create, "myqueue", 100, sizeof(msg_struct));

    msg_struct outgoing;
    outgoing.msg_type = 1;
    strncpy(outgoing.msg_name, "outgoing.msg_name", sizeof(outgoing.msg_name));

    outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ID = 42;
    strncpy(outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReportedTime, "outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReportedTime", sizeof(outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReportedTime));
    strncpy(outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReceivedAt, "outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReceivedAt", sizeof(outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReceivedAt));
    outgoing.struct_type.mess1.Number = 123;
    outgoing.struct_type.mess1.Priority = 234;

    queue.send(&outgoing, sizeof(outgoing), 1);
}
```

As you can see, this is not using Boost Serialization because the struct is POD anyways.

#### [Solution B] Highlevel C++ types, using binary serialization

Alternatively, you can use Boost Serialization all the way **and** check that the message size doesn't exceed the maximum message size when sending:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

typedef struct {
    int  msg_type;
    std::string msg_name;

    struct mess1_t {
        int  ID;
        std::string ReportedTime;
        std::string ReceivedAt;
        int  Number;
        int  Priority;
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <typename Ar>
            void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
            {
                ar & ID;
                ar & ReportedTime;
                ar & ReceivedAt;
                ar & Number;
                ar & Priority;
            }
    };

    struct mess2_t {
        std::string host_ip;
        std::string mac_addr;
        std::string time_stamp;
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <typename Ar>
            void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
            {
                ar & host_ip;
                ar & mac_addr;
                ar & time_stamp;
            }
    };

    boost::variant<mess1_t, mess2_t> message_data;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar>
        void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned)
        {
            ar & msg_type;
            ar & msg_name;
            ar & message_data;
        }
} msg_struct;

namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;

int main() {
    ipc::message_queue queue(ipc::open_or_create, "myqueue", 100, 4*1024);

    msg_struct outgoing { 1, "outgoing.msg_name", msg_struct::mess1_t {
        42,
        "outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReportedTime",
        "outgoing.struct_type.mess1.ReceivedAt",
        123,
        234 } 
    };

    std::ostringstream oss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(oss);

    oa << outgoing;

    assert(oss.str().size() <= queue.get_max_msg_size());
    queue.send(&outgoing, sizeof(outgoing), 1);
}
```

Comment: By the way, `std::string` _inside_ a struct serialized bitwise is **also** a real problem. You need to fix that.

Comment: It's difficult to be 100% positive when explaining borked code/data!

Comment: @MartinJames are you seeing different comments? I'm pretty positive about my code by the way.

Comment: The Problem was in the size .I am not removing the message queue that was previously created and when I am calling open_or_create it is opening the previously created less size queue .there fore I am getting this error.

Comment: @ali786 That makes some sense. In a way, it's about versioning of the queue then. You should probably do some detection of this situation (and start using a version indicator for your message format as well, because that could be the next thing happening when changing implementation details)